# How to query data in firestore using a valid_until field with other "orderBy"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app like a marketplace. Each item in my database has a valid_until property, so I don't want invalid (as in expired) items being returned in my queries. However, according to firestore's documentation, my first orderBy has to be the same as my range comparison.

So when I do
`ref,collection('products').orderBy('valid_until', 'desc').where('valid_until', '>=', Date.now()).limit(20)`, I get the correct result, but then I can't order by price, for example.

I also tried to do
`ref .collection("products").orderBy("valid_until", "desc").endBefore(moment().subtract(7, "days").valueOf()).limit(20)`, which also gives me the correct result but has the same issue with ordering. Each item has a validity of 7 days, hence the moment subtraction.

My other option, which I haven't tried yet, would be to schedule a task with firebase functions to delete expired products daily, so I wouldn't need to worry about querying invalid products.

Does anyone have any ideas? I think I might be missing something here. I would like to build a few number of queries in these products, such as orderBy price, valid_until, discount and so on and so forth. So I feel like this 'where' statement is blocking all other queries from happening.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just do the secondary ordering in memory in the client app?

Comment: My list is paginated, I can't see how that would work. I'd get the first 20 results, order them by discount, say, and then the next 20 wouldn't match the previous ordering, would they?

Comment: So it sounds like you're just running into known limits for Firestore. The kind of query you're trying to perform just isn't scalable in the way that Firestore requires.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I was just hoping i'd be missing something obvious hehe I guess I'll make do with your solution of ordering on the client-side and say that products are ordered like that as a feature hahaha